# SQL SERVER Select statement - How do I select one of the values for IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query as followed.  I would get multiple MethodID from the select.  Do I use while loop or another way to read each MethodID retrieved from the select to compromise the IF ELSE? (@PID
would be a input parameter)  How do I do it?

```
SELECT DISTINCT MethodID FROM Table
WHERE PID = @PID

IF @MethodID = 10
   EXEC sp1
ELSE IF @MethodID = 20
   EXEC sp2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query returns a set of `MethodID`s and the set may contain more than 1, if all you need to know is if the set contains 10, then use an `IN` or `EXISTS` clause:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table WHERE PID = @PID AND MethodID = 10))
    EXEC sp1

IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table WHERE PID = @PID AND MethodID = 20))
    EXEC sp2
```

If there are lots of cases and this query doesn't perform well, consider loading the results into a temp table.

This could also be done with `IN` clauses, but `EXISTS` is much easier in this case and *may* perform better.

Comment: You think it's only one execution? The question is unclear in that regard.

Comment: As near as I can tell, I think so.  The OP used `DISTINCT`, so 10 and 20 would each appear at most once.  They didn't look for any values other than 10 or 20.  I agree, the question is unclear.

Comment: Right my question is unclear. I would get more values from the select and more ELSE IF. Not only 10 and 20. So in this case cursor would be a better option?

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit?  I am still struggling to see why a cursor solution is needed, but since everybody else disagrees with me, there must be something I am not seeing.

Comment: after review the process again, I realized the MethodID will be an input parameter as PID, so it will only return 1 record, so I will use IF EXISTS method as Brandon suggested instead of using cursor (however cursor is another option to use).  Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Write a loop iterating over the result set of a cursor. This is a good use case for cursors because you need to perform a side-effect (a procedure call) per iteration. You need a loop anyway and a cursor is convenient to use here.

Comment: I usually recommend against cursors unless there is no alternative.

Comment: @Brandon nothing wrong with using them if you need to execute code per-row anyway. What's the disadvantage? There's no set-based solution possible here.

Comment: Yes there is.  They want to know if there is a 10 or a 20 in a set of integers.

Comment: And they want to execute a prov per row.

Comment: Perhaps I am mis-understanding the question?

Comment: Right my question is unclear. I would get more values from the select and more ELSE IF. Not only 10 and 20. So in this case would cursor be a better option?

Comment: Yes there are different MethodID returned. (10, 20, 30, 40, 50 and more, total about 10 MethodIDs.)  I want to read each MethodID returned from the SELECT in order to perform IF ELSE and do update in other tables.

Comment: Your use of `DISTINCT` results in only returning each number at most once.  The procedure call does not include any parameters from the original query, so the only question is "does this set contain a certain number", which is much simpler than a row-by-row proc call in a cursor loop.

Comment: Put another way: Do I need to run `sp1` or not?  Do I need to run `sp2` or not?  Those are boolean questions, not iterative.